# how to get the tag property (Value) of the Grand Parent Node

Tags: vb.net

I am new to the site and for VB.net as well.
I want to get the Tag value of the Grand Parent Node in a treeview control while clicking on the Grand child. I have a Tree populated from database table and for each node i set the Tag property binded to an integer number. this tree has Three Levels.

-Grand Father

--Father

---Child

-Grand Father

--Father

---Child
.
.
. and so on...

What I exactly need is , when i click on the child node then i want to store the tag value of the Grand Father of this child n a variable...

I hope you understands what i needed.
Any help will be highly Appreciated.

Comment: Use the TreeNode's Parent.Parent property to go 2 levels up.  Watch out for Nothing.